# Как правильно организовать работу React с базой данных MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, reactjs

**Здравствуйте!**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно связать работу React и базу данных MySQL?

Я пытался делать axios и fetch запросы на php файлы, которые были расположены в корневой папке, но это всегда приводило к ошибке.

Единственное решение, которое пришло мне на ум - это залить PHP файлы на бесплатный хостинг и делать запрос уже на них по ссылке. Базу данных тоже пришлось разместить на бесплатном хостинге.

Скорее всего мой подход не верный, так что попрошу у вас совета. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Способов масса идея такова что работа приложения с фронтендом на React, будет требовать бек сервис который будет обрабатывать ваши запросы с фронта. Php ли или другой вариант это будет отдельный web service у которого будет доступ к базе данных.